# Alarm not getting cancelled

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am setting the alarm in one activity, and want to cancel it in another class which is a service. Following is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SetAlarm.this, AlertFriend.class);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(SetAlarm.this, unique_id, inent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();

                 c1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                 c1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
                 c1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                 c1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c1.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

And following is where i am deleting the alarm (where a is pi):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlertFriend.class);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.cancel(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, a, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Comment: have u tried completely uninstall your app and then re-install it, and test the alarm to see if it can be cancelled?

Comment: @"where a is pi": the `a` variable cannot be `pi`. Pending intent is a result of `PendingIntent.getActivity()` and `a` in this case is an integer `requestCode`. Are you sure that `a` has the same value here as the `unique_id` while setting this alarm?